# PySpark 1.5 and Sqoop to export dataframe to SQL Server

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using PySpark 1.5 via YARN (cloudera) to create a final dataframe called 'final_table'. I have successfully exported this 'final_table' dataframe to MySQL db instance on another server via the following command.

```
final_table.write.mode('append').jdbc(url="jdbc:mysql://112.54.158.32/sys_perf?user=userbob&password=secrets",table="tps")
```

...by keeping the following commands in my .bashrc file on the Machine that I use to launch PySpark.

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/var/lib/sqoop2/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver-class-path /var/lib/sqoop2/mysql-connector-java.jar --jars /var/lib/sqoop2/mysql-connector-java.jar --master yarn --deploy-mode client"
```

However, I have not had success exporting to a SQL Server using the sql4jdbc.jar. So, I'd like to try Sqoop to export my Dataframe after I have saved it to HDFS (dir='/user/hdfs_dir1/'). I would like to just use Python subprocess to call the Sqoop command, much like I did in the bottom of my PySpark script to call this HDFS command. What would I need to pipe into the call, for sqoop? Is there anything else I need in my .bashrc, or when I launch PySpark? SEE below for example of how I used 'call' to use HDFS commands in PySpark.

```
from subprocess import call
cmd = ['hdfs','dfs','-getmerge','/user/hdfs_dir1/','/home/local_node_dir/newcsv.csv']
call(cmd)
```